# How to install old version of Git on Windows 10

Tags: git, windows-10

I need to downgrade from git version 2.14.2 to version 2.8.1. I've tried downloading the 2.8.1 files from [this link](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/), but I'm not actually sure what to do with them to install. There also seems to be conflicting answers in my google search as to whether you need to uninstall the current git version. Please let me know what I should do in order to downgrade git versions. I am using Windows 10.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to downgrade to v2.8.1 specifically and can't use the latest version available right now?

Comment: @C.AugustoProiete one reason might be to verify the behaviour of an older vs new version, perhaps in a managed corporate environment.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can get the installers of Git for Windows for previous versions in the [Releases section of the repository on GitHub](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases).

In your specific case, uninstall the current version you have, and install version 2.8.1 that you can download from here:

https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.8.1.windows.1

[image: Git for Windows v2.8.1]

Alternatively, you can use the portable version too (without having to uninstall the other version you have), but it's quick and easy to install/uninstall Git for Windows with the installer, and later you can always upgrade to a newer version using a newer installer the same way.

Answer (score 2):

I found that sometime it isn't straightforward to find an old version's full installer for on [Git for Windows' release page](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases). For example recently i tried to download `v2.22.0` for windows. However the latest one on the release page is [v2.22.0.windows.2](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.22.0.windows.2) which doesn't contain full installer, but just `MinGit-2.22.0.windows.2` etc. Had to click `Next` a few times and open each `2.22.0.windows` release to find another one [v2.22.0.windows.1](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.22.0.windows.1/Git-2.22.0-64-bit.exe) actually contains a full installer

Later I found that on [Npackd](https://www.npackd.org) it's easier to find those full installers. Just search `Git`, and find `Git for Windows` [64 bit installers](https://www.npackd.org/p/git64) and [32 bit installers](https://www.npackd.org/p/com.googlecode.msysgit.MSysGit). All download links point to `Git for Windows`' official releases on GitHub. Nice eh ***:)*** For example `Git for Windows 64 bit 2.8.1` full installer is [this](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.8.1.windows.1/Git-2.8.1-64-bit.exe).